# Add with carry on Word8

Tags: haskell, integer-overflow

I can't find a function `addWithCarry :: Word8 -> Word8 -> (Word8, Bool)` already defined in `base`. The only function documented as caring about carries seems to be `addIntC#` in `GHC.Prim` but it seems to never be pushed upwards through the various abstraction layers.

I could obviously roll out my own by testing whether the output value is in range and it's in fact what I am currently doing but I'd rather reuse an (potentially more efficient) already defined one.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: There seems to be none using exactly this type signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the source for Word8's Num instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Word.html#Word8), you'll see that everything is done by converting to a `Word#` unboxed value and performing operations on that, and then narrowing down to a 8-bit value. I suspected that doing comparison on that `Word#` value would be more efficient, so I implemented such a thing. It's [available on lpaste](http://lpaste.net/115346) (which I find easier to read than StackOverflow).

Note that it includes both a test suite and Criterion benchmark. On my system, all of the various tests take ~31ns for the boxed version (user5402's implementation) and ~24ns for the primops versions.

The important function from the lpaste above is `primops`, which is:

```
primops :: Word8 -> Word8 -> (Word8, Bool)
primops (W8# x#) (W8# y#) =
    (W8# (narrow8Word# z#), isTrue# (gtWord# z# 255##))
  where
    z# = plusWord# x# y#
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is:

```
addWithCarry :: Word8 -> Word8 -> (Word8, Bool)
addWithCarry x y = (z, carry)
  where z = x + y
        carry = z < x
```

Comment: The asker already acknowledged this solution as his current solution.