# How to temporarily cast integers to larger sizes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, casting

I have a problem with number wrapping in the following function:

```
f :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8
f a b = (a + b) `mod` 255
```

The idea is to add two numbers together, modulus 255 (note **255**, not mod **256**).

Obviously, the answer to `f 252 8` should be 260 mod 255 = 5, but the above function actually returns 4 because 252 + 8 wraps to 4 due to `Word8` being able to hold only numbers up to 255. The mod function never is never applied.

I've tried:

```
f :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8
f a b = (fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b) `mod` 255
```

thinking it will implicitly cast to `Integer` or `Int`, but it does not. What is the proper fix so that `f` doesn't suffer from the wrapping problem and isn't inefficient?

Answer (score 5):

Since you demand that it return a `Word8`, we can infer that the arguments to `mod` are both `Word8`'s, hence that the arguments to `+` are both `Word8`'s, hence that `fromIntegral` is actually being inferred to have type `Word8 -> Word8` -- probably not what you intended!

One fix is to really convert to `Integer` (or some other type as you prefer) temporarily, then back to `Word8`:

```
f a b = fromInteger ((fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b) `mod` 255)
```

Another solution is to manually check if overflow has happened.

```
f a b = (sum + if sum < a then 1 else 0) `mod` 255
    where sum = a + b
```

(The final mod operation here really is required, in case `sum` is `255` and hence no overflow happened!)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried to apply your suggestion but made a small change to the function. Now it is `f a b m = fromInteger (mod (fromIntegral a + fromIntegral b) m)` and I find it no longer works again. GHC is trying to force the function to return an `Integer`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @Ana since you have now abstracted the modulus, `m`, may I assume you have also given it a type `Word8`?  You are probably looking for `fromIntegral m`.

Comment: Checking for both conditions sum < a or sum < b looks nicely symmetric, but either inequality implies the other.

Comment: @j.p. Cute! I'll put that in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can delve into low-level Haskell and use primitive operations. I've been pointed in this direction by [Michael Snoyman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205171/727667) to a related question of mine. Here we don't need to narrow the result because the remainder operation (`remWord#`) should always deliver a number small enough:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

module Word8Mod where

import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Word

f :: Word8 -> Word8 -> Word8
f (W8# x#) (W8# y#) =
  let z# = plusWord# x# y#
  in W8# (remWord# z# (int2Word# 255#))
```

Comment: Notice this is not low level Haskell but actually GHC primitives.

Comment: What would you call low-level?

Comment: It isn't about defining "low level" but calling GHC primitive operations "Haskell" is misleading.